# Regex to replace what's inside the bracket except the another brackets inside of it

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

How to replace what's inside the bracket except the another brackets inside of it. Replace to `ZZZZZ`.

```
{
 "0000" "1111"
 1111
 { 222 }
 { 333 }
}
```

will be:

```
{
 ZZZZZ
 { 222 }
 { 333 }
}
```

Comment: Will the text you're replacing always follow the opening bracket? If you provide more examples, we will be able to see the actual structure of the data. This kind of regex is much more difficult if the text you're searching for could be anywhere among the other brackets, and if the brackets can be arbitrarily nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
({\n\s*)(?:[^}{]*)(\n\s*{)
```

First, within a capturing group, `()`, match `{`, then a newline `\n`, then any amount of space.

```
({\n\s*)
```

Next, within a non-capturing group, match anything that is **not** `}{`, any number of times.

```
(?:[^}{]*)
```

Finally, closing similarly to how we started: Capture the newline, any amount of whitespace, and the next opening `{`.

```
(\n\s*{)
```

This won't match ones without internal brackets, nor will it work if the internal brackets are nested to 3 layers. If you provide some examples of your input, we can improve the match (like using a look behind to skip internal matches)

See a [demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aK7dH6/9)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it works! But how about if there is a line-break? I tried putting a line-break but it doesn't work. Also I've tried putting a 4 quotation mark for 2 string in 1 line, and it failed to work. Please I need your help.

Comment: @MomarMaute Can you update your question with an example of that format?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have updated the post/question. Thanks a lot @TemporalWolf

Comment: @MomarMaute Removing the `\s` from the negative set has covered that additional test. I've updated the post and regex101 demo. EDIT: Had to make a bugfix.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TemporalWolf . Sorry I can't vote up but your answer really works. I hope some people out there are looking for this, the same as my problem.

Comment: @MomarMaute You're welcome and welcome to StackOverflow. There is an FAQ entry on [what to do when someone answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: BTW, I have another Q, how to inverse the selected result or inverse the matched? I can't find a solution in search result nor in google.

Comment: @MomarMaute If you have a different question, feel free to post another question. Just try to post as much information up front as possible so people don't need to ask clarifying questions... as I'm not sure what you want from this comment.

Comment: Ok. but this is my last question. Where can I download a notepad program for PCRE Regex, because on my Notepad++, replacing doesn't not. I keep searching on google but I found nothing. Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick `(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\{)`

[image]

This will match everything in between `{` & `{`. 
 New line characters are not included in this regex. For this to work properly with notepad++, the checkbox "matches newline" within the find/replace window needs to be checked.

Comment: @TemporalWolf
Not in notepad++ it doesn't - with the "matches newline" checkbox checked